# RhoMobile and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, rhomobile

Just out of interest, is it possible to compile a RhoMobile application using the prerequisite libraries provided by Visual Studio 2012. At the moment, I have been using a demo of Visual Studio 2008 to do all compilation and accordingly I would like to continue my development with Visual Studio 2012. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Windows Mobile or Windows Embedded Handheld your only option is to use Visual Studio 2008.
This is not a limitation of RhoMobile, but Microsoft decided to not include the support for Windows Mobile in Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012.